# Protecting Media files on REACT web

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mern

I'm hosting a online streaming service using a MERN stack, while keeping my media files on S3 bucket.
I need to my media to be accessible only through my app and not be downloadable neither by right clicking and using browser menu nor by actually visiting the media link which can be fetched by viewing source among other stuff. What options do I have?
I'm using this https://github.com/CookPete/react-player#supported-media as a media player.

Comment: I think that this is not possible, since you send all the relevant data to the client and you can't block the client to do whatever he wants with the data.

Comment: @jrenk taking an example of online radio, we do get there audio to listen but that's it. We can't do anything further than that with it. It's something like that I'm looking for. I feel it's not something like inventing the wheel, but still I'm missing on.